# Is a function definition an object?

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object and a function definition:

```
var jane = {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    describe: function () {
        return 'Person named '+this.firstName+this.lastName
    },
};

function Car (desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = function getInfo() {
        return 'A ' + this.color + ' ' + this.desc + '.';
    };
}
```

I can enumerate over the object's key:value pairs thus:

```
obj=jane
for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log(`obj.${prop} = ${obj[prop]}`);
}
```

but this fails for the function definition (same for function expression)

```
obj=Car.....
```

If a function definition is an object then why can't I enumerate over it's properties? Is there a way do to it?

Thanks

Comment: `Car` is a type of thing, `new Car` will be the thing itself. `this.desc` applies to the thing itself.

Comment: so you cant iterate over a type of thing?

Comment: Well you can, but you haven't defined any properties on the "type of thing" yet. Try `Car.defaultWheelCount = 4;` and see what you get.

Comment: well that produces a 'thing' in your terminology, it doesn't affect the function definition. Are you saying as far as 'JavaScript' is concerned the function definition key:values is just a block of characters we can't interrogate?

Comment: @Eggy Generally speaking you can't predict what properties would constructor add to the instance w/o calling it with given arguments. `function Car(){ this[Math.random()] = Math.random()}` So you need to create an instance first `var aCar = new Car('test')` and only then inspect properties.

Comment: *but this fails* -> what is this? Your function object has no properties yet...

Comment: @Yury Ok, but conceptually there isn't a reason that you cant interrogate the function definition - I mean you can parse the text and do it manually! But perhaps internally JavaScript doesn't store the key:value pairs for the function definition then?

Comment: No Eggy. You haven't set any key:value pairs on the function definition. Your function defines them for the newly created instance.

Comment: @Neit @ Jonas w I know I dont have an instance of the function definition. But grammatically the body is set out in key:value pairs. It is possible that javascript has internal methods which allow you to parse these properties in their textual form. Maybe there arent any though :)

Comment: @Eggy Conceptually there is turing completness. You can't even predict if it terminates or not. :) Plus js functions are not even required to be pure. Go ahead and parse `function Car(){ this[Math.random()] = Math.random()}` :)

Comment: `grammatically the body is set out in key:value pairs` - but set on a different object (whatever `this` will be bound to), not on the Function definition itself

Comment: hmm, but maybe you are looking for [`Car.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)?

Comment: @Aprillion no toString() just brings back a blob of text which'll need parsing into key:value pairs manually

Comment: what is ``obj.${prop} = ${obj[prop]}`` called?I have never used it anywhere ever.

Answer (score 2):

Lets imagine youre standing in front of a car factory. Can you predict which car will leave it next? Or maybe the factory is closed and will return nothing?

```
import Car from "factory";
var car=new Car();//what will car be?
```

So basically you cannot predict what a constructor will construct. But if the car factory just produces diesel engines, we can find that out through the prototype chain, e.g:

```
new Car() instanceof Diesel;//true
new Car instanceof Car;//true => all cars have the same prototype ( Car.prototype)
```

So coming back to your example it would make sense to use inheritance like this if the properties are static:

```
function Car (desc) {
this.desc = desc;//unpredictable
}
Car.prototype={
  color:"red",//predictable, every car inherits from this
  getInfo() {
    return 'A ' + this.color + ' ' + this.desc + '.';
  },
};
```

So to get the static properties, you could iterate over the prototype:

```
for(key in Car.prototype);//iterates over color and getInfo
```

Comment: I see. It's interesting the prototype is iterable but not the function definition itself.

Comment: @eggy the function is iterable too. But you want to iterate sth that does not exist yet (=>unpredictable = impossible)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesn't really matter what options the constructor has, we dont need to predict actual values. I just wanted the key:value function definition pairs as is. We can do it by parsing. JavaScript seemingly doesnt expose them in that way via internal methods

Comment: @eggy why?? Isnt it more easy to simply extract them manualy? And you dont want real values but key:value pairs??? That does not make sense

Comment: Ok, say I want to interrogate 1000 function definitions for duplicate key names. Given a duplicate I want to test for differences in default values. Its not my code. I can't adjust it or even run it meaningfully. It'd be nice to be able to just iterate over the FD's wouldn't it?

Comment: @eggy why do you need this? If its some API, it should have a documentation which contains all the infos. And i dont think that sth like "key":"getKey()" is really useful. You still dont know what getKey() evaluates to, and youll never know...

Comment: Those sort of things are useful and queryable in code databases eg sql. But actually I don't "need" it, it's a thought experiment :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case `this` refers to global object `window` or to `undefined` in strict mode.
Use it as constructor:
`obj = new Car(desc)`

Comment: yes, then I just have an object. I'm asking if I can iterate over the function definition itself in some way

Answer (score 0):

while Functions are Objects, properties of the `this` special Object inside a Function are not [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) in the `for...in` loop over the Function itself...

if you don't like the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator which [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)s `this` onto a new Object, making it's properties enumerable on that new object, feel free to [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) it with explicit `this` argument like this:

```
var obj = {};
Car.call(obj);
```

```js
function Car(desc) {
  this.desc = desc;
  this.color = "red";
  this.getInfo = function getInfo() {
    return 'A ' + this.color + ' ' + this.desc + '.';
  };
}

var obj = {};
Car.call(obj);

for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log(`obj.${prop} = ${obj[prop]}`);
}
```

One more complicated route starts with parsing the function source code:  [`Car.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString):

```
function simpleThisInspector(constructorFn) {
  const source = constructorFn.toString()
  const thisProps = {}
  // TODO: nested {} blocks and non-block multiline statements not supported
  const re = /this\.(\w+)\s*=\s*([^;\n{]*(?:\{[^}]*})?)/g  // https://regex101.com/r/aJzgjx/1
  let match
  while(match = re.exec(source)) {
    thisProps[match[1]] = match[2]
  }
  return thisProps
}

var obj = simpleThisInspector(Car)
```

```js
function simpleThisInspector(constructorFn) {
  const source = constructorFn.toString()
  const thisProps = {}
  // TODO: nested {} blocks and non-block multiline statements not supported
  const re = /this\.(\w+)\s*=\s*([^;\n{]*(?:\{[^}]*})?)/g  // https://regex101.com/r/aJzgjx/1
  let match
  while(match = re.exec(source)) {
    thisProps[match[1]] = match[2]
  }
  return thisProps
}

function Car(desc) {
  this.desc = desc;
  this.color = "red";
  this.getInfo = function getInfo() {
    return 'A ' + this.color + ' ' + this.desc + '.';
  };
}

var obj = simpleThisInspector(Car)

for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log(`obj.${prop} = ${obj[prop]}`);
}
```

Comment: Ok, well, if it can't be done, it can't be done  :) Thanks for your alternative. Yes I mentioned the manual parsing alternate in another response.

Comment: @Eggy if you give me 10 minutes, I will try to parse the source code string, it would be a fun exercise... but I guess I wouldn't recommend my simple version in production code :D you might want to explore some serious parser, e.g. have a look at https://astexplorer.net/

Comment: Ok. Have fun :) I asked Q because I wanted to understand conceptually the way Functions/Objects/properties tie in together as I'm just getting to grips with JavaScript :) And I dont see why being able to interrogate function definitions in this way wouldn't be useful!

Comment: well, you can just not use the constructor Function with `this` and use plain objects instead...

Comment: Yep, your parser produces the type of thing I was looking for. Well done :) btw re plain object etc comment  its about taking existing functions and interrogating it, not writing new functions/objects etc

Comment: @eggy if you need to parse your own code manually, you did sth very very wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a function definition is an object, but what you are trying to achieve is iterate over something which is declared **inside** of that function, which is impossible (imagine trying to iterate over a function's local variables - seems silly, and you have a kind of similar concept). You can always try

```
obj = new Car("dummy");
```

which would iterate over the object returned by the function. Without calling `new` there is no way of accessing these properties from the outside.

Notice that these properties are not properties defined on the function object. They are properties of an object returned by that function. So JavaScript would need some new syntax for this, because using a simple `for .. in` loop would be a breaking change.

Comment: I get what you are saying if you are talking about "code". I'm not. Whether JavaScript can do it or not (obviously the interpreter does it to produce runnable code) doesn't mean that its not a reasonable requirement to want to parse out the key:value pairs of a function definition

Comment: Notice that these properties are not properties defined on the function objects. They are properties of an object returned by that function. So JavaScript would need some new syntax for this, because using a simple `for .. in` loop would be a breaking change. But I agree with you that it is theoretically possible to implement. At this time such feature does not exist, though.

Comment: I was agreeing with this "But I agree with you that it is theoretically possible to implement. At this time such feature does not exist, though". :)